# Output from scatter3d R script - how to read the equation

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am using scatter3d to find a fit in my R script. I did so, and here is the output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ (x + z)^2 + I(x^2) + I(z^2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.78454 -0.02302 -0.00563  0.01398  0.47846 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.051975   0.003945 -13.173  < 2e-16 ***
x            0.224564   0.023059   9.739  < 2e-16 ***
z            0.356314   0.021782  16.358  < 2e-16 ***
I(x^2)      -0.340781   0.044835  -7.601 3.46e-14 ***
I(z^2)       0.610344   0.028421  21.475  < 2e-16 ***
x:z         -0.454826   0.065632  -6.930 4.71e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Residual standard error: 0.05468 on 5293 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6129, Adjusted R-squared: 0.6125 
F-statistic:  1676 on 5 and 5293 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Based on this, what is the equation of the best fit line? I'm not really sure how to read this? Can someone explain? thanks!

Comment: I would start with `?lm` which is the help file for the `lm` function

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [rsm R pacakge](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsm/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a plane but rather a paraboloid surface (and using 'y' as the third dimension since you used 'z' already):

```
y =  -0.051975 + x * 0.224564  + z * 0.356314  +
          -x^2 * -0.340781 + z^2 * 0.610344 - x * z * 0.454826
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic regression output table. The parameter estimates ("Estimate" column) are the best-fit line coefficients corresponding to the different terms in your model. If you aren't familiar with this terminology, I would suggest reading up on some linear model and regression tutorial. There are thousands around the web. I would also encourage you to play with some simpler 2D simulations.

For example, let's make some data with an intercept of 2 and a slope of 0.5:

```
# Simulate data
set.seed(12345)
x = seq(0, 10, len=50)
y = 2 + 0.5 * x + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.1)
data = data.frame(x, y)
```

Now when we look at the fit, you'll see that the Estimate column shows these same values:

```
# Fit model
fit = lm(y ~ x, data=data)
summary(fit)
```

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.26017 -0.06434  0.02539  0.06238  0.20008 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.011759   0.030856   65.20   <2e-16 ***
x           0.501240   0.005317   94.27   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.1107 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9946, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9945 
F-statistic:  8886 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Pulling these out, we can then plot the best-fit line:

```
# Make plot
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
plot(x, y, ylim=c(0,10))
abline(fit$coef[1], fit$coef[2])
```

[image]

Comment: but I don't have an lm object, I have a scatter3d object

Comment: The lm summary is part of what scatter3d has returned. You can access all its elements just like you would if you had only fit the model from the command line. I would HIGHLY recommend picking up an intro R book for this type of stuff. There are many, and they all cover these basics thoroughly. Also look at the many free texts on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html . Or google some combination of "r regression example guide tutorial".