# Overlay surface to 3d points

Tags: r, 3d

Suppose I have a 3D point cloud represented by:

```
arv = data.frame(axis_x = rnorm(n=300, mean=-0.20, sd=1.01),
             axis_y = rnorm(n=300, mean=-0.45, sd=0.97),
             elevation = rnorm(n=300, mean=-813.2, sd=13.89))
```

And I also have a paraboloid modeled by:

```
model = lm(formula = elevation ~ (axis_x + axis_y)^2 + I(axis_x^2) + I(axis_y^2), data = arv)
```

Is it some way to plot **both** (the points and model) together in a 3D plot?

Comment: I'm not sure whether to downvote as duplicated or post an answer expanding upon the values of using `pkg:rgl` and function `car:scatter3d`: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044589/output-from-scatter3d-r-script-how-to-read-the-equation

Comment: @DWin my question is clearly different from that one you linked. Technically, I can't solve my problem just looking your link. Thus, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with `persp()` and `trans3d`. To improve clarity, it helps to connect the observed values to the 3d surface of the function with lines:

```
# data
arv = data.frame(axis_x = rnorm(n=300, mean=-0.20, sd=1.01),
             axis_y = rnorm(n=300, mean=-0.45, sd=0.97),
             elevation = rnorm(n=300, mean=-813.2, sd=13.89))
# fit             
model = lm(formula = elevation ~ (axis_x + axis_y)^2 + I(axis_x^2) + I(axis_y^2), data = arv)

# grid for plotting function
x <- seq(min(arv$axis_x), max(arv$axis_x), length.out = 20)
y <- seq(min(arv$axis_y), max(arv$axis_y), length.out = 20)

# function for predicted surface from model
f <- function(x, y) { cbind(1,x,y,x^2,y^2,x*y) %*% coef(model) }

# predicted values in form that persp() can use
z <- outer(x, y, f)

# 3d plot of surface with persp()
ele_3d <- persp(x=x,y=y,z=z, theta=40, phi=15, zlim=c(min(arv$elevation), max(arv$elevation)) )

# transform observed values into 2d space
elevation_points <- trans3d(arv$axis_x, arv$axis_y, arv$elevation, pmat=ele_3d)

# plot observed values
points(elevation_points)

# add dotted lines from surface to observed values
fit_vals <- trans3d(arv$axis_x, arv$axis_y, fitted(model), pmat = ele_3d)
segments(fit_vals$x, fit_vals$y, elevation_points$x, elevation_points$y, lty = 3)
```

Another option is to use a panel function with `wireframe()` in lattice. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406202/plotting-a-wireframe-and-a-cloud-with-lattice-in-r).

Comment: I'm upvoting with reservations. This is an excellent answer to the specific question of "how to plot", but the use of the `I()` function in an `lm()` call may lead newbies to believe that this is the right way to construct linear models for statistical analysis of polynomial models ...  and it is not.

Comment: @DWin the call to `lm()` mirrors the OP's code chunk. Would use `poly()` but prefer to keep the code consistent with the OP.

Comment: Just posting a warning for newbies. As I said, I thought your answer was on point, but only in a narrow interpretation of "on point". Not generalizable.